# How to make a case sensitive string compare in Python?

Tags: python, string

I am trying to write a code that compares two strings and return the string if a match is found with the case sensitive condition except for the capital. That's the function I have wrote and I have learned that == is pretty good for comparing  case sensitively. However it still prints January for the last test line which is not expected.   So can you help me out please?

```
  months = ['January',
      'February',
      'March',
      'April',
      'May',
      'June',
      'July',
      'August',
      'September',
      'October',
      'November',
      'December']

  def valid_month(month):
     for x in months:
         if x==month.capitalize() :
             print x
```

Test codes:

```
  valid_month("january")  
  valid_month("January")
  valid_month("foo") 
  valid_month("") 
  valid_month("jaNuary")
```

Comment: you are calling capitalize on the string passed in which causes it to be "Capital"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this:

```
def valid_month(month):
    for x in months:
        if x[1:] == month[1:] and x[0].capitalize() == month[0].capitalize():
            print x
```

This will test equality with case sensitivity - except for the first character.

Answer (score 3):

it's because `"janUAry".capitalize()` is equal to `"January"`

```
In [4]: "January"=="janUAry".capitalize()
Out[4]: True
```

A better version of your code can be :

```
def valid_month(month):
     if month and month[0].capitalize()+month[1:] in months:
         print(month)
     else:
         print(month,"is not found")
```

**output:**

```
>>> valid_month("january")
january
>>> valid_month("January")
January
>>> valid_month("foo")
foo is not found
>>> valid_month("")
 is not found
>>> valid_month("jaNuary")
jaNuary is not found
```

Comment: but I think he wants to match 'january'

Comment: @JoranBeasley I guess I missed that, i think in that case `if month and month[0].capitalize()+month[1:] in months:` will do fine.

Comment: yeah its easy to fix ... but was worth mentioning

Answer (score 2):

`capitalize` transforms your string to lower case but for the first letter which becomes upper case. So, `"jaNuary".capitalize()` becomes `"January"` and your test is correct.

Obviously, that's not the right approach. You could check whether any letter but the first is a upper case:

```
any(t.isupper() for t in month[1:])
```

and fails if that's the case.